# Conditional where condition in GraphQL Query

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo

i have the following query:

```
query MyExampleQuery($templateQuestionId: Int!, $assetId: Int) {
  report_answer(
    where: { 
      report_template_question: { id: { _eq: $templateQuestionId } }, 
      asset_id: { _eq: $assetId } }
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

and i want the asset_id condition of the where only apply conditionally. When $assetId is provided it should be a condition, otherwise it should not apply at all.

**How can this be achieved with GraphQL?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes but not in the way you have described above.

You have:

```
query MyExampleQuery($templateQuestionId: Int!, $assetId: Int)
```

Which says that `$templateQuestionId` is required but `$assetId` is optional.

When you write your *resolver* for this query you can take the existence (or absence) of `assetId` into account when you execute an actual database query.

But the GraphQL language itself does not have the concept of a `where` clause. Some GraphQL APIs include a `where` in their input objects but it's not part of the language.